# Doubly Linked List no imports

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

I'm currently working on Junit testing for implementing a Doubly Linked list in java. I understand how it needs to work *drawn pictures over and over* but I cannot get my removeFirst method to work. `addLast();` works up until removeFirst is called.

```
private Link<I> first;
private Link<I> last;

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return size() == 0;
}

public int size() {
    int count = 0;
    Link<I> aLink = first;
    while (aLink != null) {
        count++;
        aLink = aLink.getAfter();
    }
    return count;
}

public I get(int index) {
    Link<I> aLink = first;
    int count = 0;
    while (count != index) {
        aLink = aLink.getAfter();
        count++;
    }
    return aLink.getItem();

}

public void addLast(I anItem) {
    Link<I> aLink = new Link<I>(anItem);
    if (isEmpty()) {
        first = aLink;
        first = last;
    } else {
        last.setAfter(aLink);
        aLink.setBefore(last);
        last = aLink;

    }
}

public void addFirst(I anItem) {
    Link<I> aLink = new Link<I>(anItem);
    if (isEmpty()) {
        first = aLink;
        last = first;
    } else {
        aLink.setAfter(first);
        first.setBefore(last);
        first = aLink;
    }

}

public I removeFirst() {
    I removed = first.get(0);
    if(size()==3) {
        first = first.getAfter();
        first.setBefore(null);
        first.setAfter(last);
        return removed;
    } else if(size()==2) {
        first = first.getAfter();
        first.setBefore(null);
        first.setAfter(null);
        return removed;
    }else {
        first = null;
        first.setBefore(null);
        first.setAfter(null);
        return removed;
    }

}

public I removeLast() {
    I removed = last.getItem();
    if (isEmpty()) {
        removed = null;
        return removed;
    } else {
        last = last.getBefore();
        removed = last.getItem();
        return removed;
    }

}
```

}

```
public class Link<I> {
private Link<I> after;
private Link<I> before;
private I item;

public Link(I anItem) {
    item = anItem;
}

public Link<I> getAfter(){
    return after;
}

public void setAfter(Link<I> aLink) {
    after = aLink;
}

public Link<I> getBefore(){
    return before;
}

public void setBefore(Link<I> aLink) {
    before = aLink;
}

public I getItem() {
    return item;
}

public void setItem(I anItem) {
    item = anItem;
}
```

}

here is the test unit

```
void testAddLast() {
    notes.addLast("do");
    notes.addLast("re");
    notes.addLast("mi");
    String note = notes.removeFirst();
    assertTrue(notes.size()==2);
    assertTrue("do".equals(note));
    note = notes.removeFirst();
    assertTrue(notes.size()==1);
    assertTrue("re".equals(note));
    note= notes.removeFirst();
    assertTrue(notes.isEmpty());
    assertTrue("mi".equals(note));
    note = notes.removeFirst();
    assertTrue(note == null);
    assertTrue(notes.isEmpty());
    assertTrue(notes.size() == 0);
}
```

I feel like what I have now is getting me close but `I removed = first.get(0);` keeps giving me a null pointer exception. 
I was given extra time on this assignment over 2 weeks ago and I am still having a really hard time with this. I have tried a bunch of variations of the removeFirst() method following the debugger to help.

any insight would help me alot. I have more test cases I can add to post aswell.

Comment: I don't see I `removed = first.get(0);` anywhere in your code

Comment: edited. It is in the removeFirst method. first line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be the method that's giving you trouble

```
public I removeFirst() {
    I removed = first.get(0);
    if(size()==3) {
        first = first.getAfter();
        first.setBefore(null);
        first.setAfter(last);
        return removed;
    } else if(size()==2) {
        first = first.getAfter();
        first.setBefore(null);
        first.setAfter(null);
        return removed;
    }else {
        first = null;
        first.setBefore(null);
        first.setAfter(null);
        return removed;
    }

}
```

You say you're getting a NullPointerException when you call `first.get(0)`. This means that `first` is null.

This is how you add a node:

```
public void addLast(I anItem) {
    Link<I> aLink = new Link<I>(anItem);
    if (isEmpty()) {
        first = aLink;
        first = last;
    } else {
        last.setAfter(aLink);
        aLink.setBefore(last);
        last = aLink;
    }
}
```

You assign to `first` `aLink`, then overwrite that assignment with `last`, which is null.

You probably means to say `last = first` there.

Try this test case:

```
void testAddOne() {
    assertTrue(notes.count() == 0);
    notes.addLast("do");
    assertTrue(notes.count() == 1);
}
```

Generally, your test case is very complicated. You want simpler tests to check the postconditions of an operations. For example, inserting one element should increase the count by one. Removing an element should decrease the count by one. Adding two elements, check get returns the first for index 0 and the second for index 1, and so on.

Comment: well changing `first = last` passed testAddOne but I am still receiving the null pointer exception. however I noted that on the last removeTest that first is null and last = "mi"

Comment: So Ive gotten everything to the point that the list is empty `first = null` and `last = null`. However the 4th removeFirst() is failing *I think because of the null pointer exception. there are only 3 items in the list so should I return null or something else for the very last removeFirst

Comment: Nevermind I just moved `I removed = get(0);` into the if statements it applies to and I am greenlighting thanks for the help.

Comment: @TresTheGoat I'm glad it helped! If this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.